# adapting collision detection code to other sides

Tags: python-2.7, pygame

I have developed a function that searches for a wall in the direction the sprite is moving in, but so far I have only got it to work for downwards movement and cannot get it to work for left and right. the function is as follows:

```
def CFW(DirectionMoving):
    for a in WallList:
        if DirectionMoving == 0: #0=down
            if a[0] > (plyposx-30) and a[0] < (plyposx+30): #a[0] is x coord for the wall
                return 1 #positive for wall
            else:
                return 0 #negative for wall
```

and this is the non-working code for left and right:

```
        elif DirectionMoving == 1: #1=left
            if a[1] > (plyposy-30) and a[1] < (plyposy+30):
                return 1
            else:
                return 0
```

if anyone could work out why this does not work for left and right I would appreciate the help.

Comment: What is `a`, a sprite, or a list of points or?

Answer (score 0):

```
elif DirectionMoving == 1: #1=left
    if a[1] > (plyposy-30) and a[1] < (plyposy+30):
        return 1
    else:
        return 0
```

Does this code ever get entered? Let's change it a bit so you can see what's happening.

```
elif DirectionMoving == 1: #1=left
    print 'dbg: moving left'
    if a[1] > (plyposy-30) and a[1] < (plyposy+30):
        print 'dbg: moving left - condition met'
        return 1
    else:
        print 'dbg: moving left - condition not met'
        return 0
```

When you've found that out, change it again.

```
elif DirectionMoving == 1: #1=left
    return a[1] > (plyposy-30) and a[1] < (plyposy+30)
```

Comment: Aha! I have discovered that the function was not being run by the sprite controller for conformation! I am very grateful for you help.

Comment: Glad to be of service. Be sure to remember this useful technique when you are stuck again or unsure of the program's behavior.